# How escape or sanatize slash using regex in R?

Tags: r, escaping, backslash, slash

I'm trying to read in a (tab separted) csv file in R. When I want to read the column including a `/`, I get an error.

```
doSomething <- function(dataset) {
     a <- dataset$data_transfer.Jingle/TCP.total_size_kb
     ...
     }
```

The error says, that this object cannot be found. I've tried escaping with backslash but it did not work.

If anybody has got some idea, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give

```
head(dataset)
```

and watch the name it has been given. Perhaps it would be something like:

```
dataset$data_transfer.Jingle.TCP.total_size_kb
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

```
dataset[["data_transfer.Jingle/TCP.total_size_kb"]]
```

or

```
dataset$`data_transfer.Jingle/TCP.total_size_kb`
```

Comment: This is really helpful if the variable name in the dataset really does have a forward slash (assigned in some way other than direct import).